# Compare one varchar with another varchar based on word similarity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two varchar's and I am trying to compare and display based on the similarity of the words in the varchar. For example if I have the string: "hello mellow fellow" and compare it with a table containing:

"hello ocean man"
"goodbye computer thing"
"hello fellow cactus"

It would then display the results based on how many words they have in common like:

"hello fellow cactus"
"hello ocean man"
"goodbye computer thing"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results? Please read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help section. Without showing us what attempts you have made to resolve your issue and what error/results you achieved, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do that by tokenizing your original statement, and each of other statements, count the intersection between two resulting arrays and order accordingly, here is sample code:

```php
<?php

$myPhrase = "hello mellow fellow";
$otherPhrases = ["hello ocean man", "goodbye computer thing", "hello fellow cactus"];
$resultsOrdered = [];


$myWords = explode(" ", $myPhrase);
foreach($otherPhrases as $otherPhrase) {
    $otherWords = explode(" ", $otherPhrase);
    $intersectWords = array_intersect($myWords, $otherWords);
    $resultsOrdered[$otherPhrase] = count($intersectWords);
}

arsort($resultsOrdered);

foreach($resultsOrdered as $phrase => $wordCountInCommon) {
    echo $phrase." (".$wordCountInCommon. " words in common)".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I realize you are relatively new to Stack Overflow (SO) and you are eager to increase your reputation score, but please be reminded that SO is not a place to come to so that others will write code for you. Please refrain from providing answers to questions that do not meet the guidelines of [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @Kuya thank for you the advice, I will pay attention to that next time